# Making one table in R

Tags: r

I am learning programming languages for the first time. I am trying to combine tables in R using:

Trip_data <- bind_rows(oct_td, sep_td, aug_td,jul_td, jun_td,may_td)

and I get the following error:

Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Value of SET_STRING_ELT() must be a 'CHARSXP' not a 'symbol'
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

What does that means? and how do I solve it?

I have another set of tables and I managed to combine them just fine, I also ran that yesterday and I did not get an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO Ednah! It would help a lot to shrink down the code to just two files in the rbind, and to post the contents of those two files.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I reduced the files and it worked out just fine. In the future, I will take your advice on reproducing the problem.